# Parse query does not work

Tags: android, parse-platform

The problem just like the title, I tried to count the user (I defined) who have the same name, I used `countinbackground` or `findinbackground`, no matter what I did, the count is always `0`. Does anyone can help me, I don't know why. Thanks a lot. Below is my code:

```
public boolean checknameunique(String n) {

boolean notexist = true;
ParseQuery<Userdata> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Userdata.class);
query.whereEqualTo("name", n);
/*query.countInBackground(new CountCallback() {
    public void done(int count, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            name_count = count;
        }
    }
});*/
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Userdata>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<Userdata> objects, ParseException e) {
        if(e==null) {
            int size = objects.size();
            name_count = size;
        }
    }
});
if(name_count>0) {
    notexist = false;
    Toast.makeText(this,
            "Username already exist",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
return notexist;
}
```

Comment: `findInBackground` is asynchronous–won't `name_count` always be `undefined`? Put your `Toast` inside the `done` block to see what I mean :)

Comment: move the 'if(name_count > 0)' block inside your done function and do whatever you intended to do based on the value of 'notexist' inside there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not aware that findInBackground method is asynchronous, that is why you have that callback inside. You probably want to learn a bit more about threads and async tasks in Android and Parse.

Here is the correct code you would want to have:

```
public void checknameunique(String n) {

    ParseQuery<Userdata> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Userdata.class);
    query.whereEqualTo("name", n);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Userdata>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Userdata> res, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null) {
                int size = res.size();

                if(res.size() > 0) {
                    showMessage("Username already exist");
                } else {
                    proceed();
                }
            } else {
                showMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

private void showMessage(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private void proceed() {
    //TODO:
}
```